# BigQuery to find the Subsequence

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, subsequence

Assuming my table is

```
WITH `sample_project.sample_dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'user1' user, 2 sequence, 'T1' ts UNION ALL
  SELECT 'user1', 2, 'T2' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'user1', 1, 'T3' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'user1', 1, 'T4' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'user1', 3, 'T5' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'user1', 2, 'T6' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'user1', 3, 'T7' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'user1', 3, 'T8' 
)
```

Can I find Subsequence of Integers available in sequence column without using STRING_AGG and REGEX OR JOIN operations  ? This is to make query more efficient.

A subsequence is a part of String. For example consider String "banana", A sample subsequence is "anna" as each index character of "anna" from banana is strictly increasing. Characters in a subsequence need not be contiguous.

Say for the above table when order by timestamp (INCREASING), I would get STRING_AGG for sequence column as 22113233. In the String 22113233 subsequence `1 2 3` is available whereas subsequence `3 2 1` is **not** available. Given a subsequence `213`, How can I say if this subsequence is available or not (in `22113233` which sorted by timestamp) ?

Comment: what would be definition of subsequence? please explain logic. and why you want to avoid string_agg? how you would otherwise construct final subsequence list string

Comment: i see update, but sorry, i am still not getting the logic applicable to the data example you provided.

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I have added the definition of subsequence. My Query is working good with STRING_AGG and REGEX, but the problem is the number of items of `sequence` column for a particular user which is very large whereas the length of subsequence of items that I want to search is very small. I am curious if I can optimise here.

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant Am I able to explain it more clearly ?

Comment: what you mean by "Can I find a given ..."  - I just don't get it! if you think you explained it very clearly and nothing more to clarify  - someone else might be able to help

Comment: i think now it is clear :o) even though it is still confusing that you want to eliminate string_agg - how you would get `22113233` without string_agg!

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Given a subsequence 213, How can I say if this subsequence is available or not (in 22113233 ...

Below example is for BigQuery SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `sequences` AS (
  SELECT '22113233' sequence_list 
), `subsequenses` AS (
  SELECT '123' subsequence UNION ALL
  SELECT '321' UNION ALL
  SELECT '213'
)
SELECT sequence_list, subsequence, 
  REGEXP_CONTAINS(sequence_list, REGEXP_REPLACE(subsequence, '', '.*')) available
FROM `sequences` l
CROSS JOIN `subsequenses` s
```

with result as below

```sql
sequence_list   subsequence     available    
22113233        321             false    
22113233        123             true     
22113233        213             true
```

if you are looking for specific subsequence - this can be further simplified as

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `sequences` AS (
  SELECT '22113233' sequence_list UNION ALL
  SELECT '11223322'
)
SELECT sequence_list,  
  REGEXP_CONTAINS(sequence_list, REGEXP_REPLACE('213', '', '.*')) available
FROM `sequences`
```

with result as

```sql
sequence_list   available    
22113233        true     
11223322        false
```

Comment: Can I find Subsequence of Integers available in sequence column without using STRING_AGG and REGEX OR JOIN operations ? This is to make query more efficient. I wanted to solve this without using this in order to optimise it, rather than keeping every Integer of the sequence column to construct sequence list.

Comment: I have used STRING_AGG and REGEX which is taking more time.. I want to optimise it

Comment: sorry for comparison but what you ask sounds equivalent to me if you ask to write sql without using sql. if i will get an idea how to avoid STRING_AGG and REGEXP here - i will definitelly reply again. But i don't think it will be more optimal then using those!

Comment: Thanks @MikhailBerlyant . Rather than doing STRING_AGG and then doing REGEX, can we just look for subsequence while during AGGREGATING and mark it true/false ?

Comment: Technically, it is doable - but I doubt it will be more optimal as it still will involve JOINing and extra handling of orders. so I doubt it will be better.

Comment: I am happy that we both agree it is doable. I am curious if for a user I have one billion entries in `sequence` column and if I am interested in finding subsequence `123` which I may be can find in first 1 million, so that I don't need other 99 million to store, thereby reducing shuffling and other computational costs..

Comment: i don't think this is going to work this way! what I can recommend - if this will fit into your business requirements - is to introduce some sort of  threshold - let's say expected pattern should be within 1000 neighboring rows - in this case you can use analytic windowed functions - and this can optimize your stuff i think

Comment: Thanks for suggesting analytic windowed functions. I will have a closer look at them.

Comment: sure. please note - that suggestion will work if you can introduce that "neighboring" threshold :o)