# Lead & Analytical Functions in BigQuery

Tags: sql, performance, join, google-bigquery, state

Assume my table is this

[image]

I am trying to modify my table with this information

[image]

I have added two columns where column `WhenWasLastBasicSubjectDone` will let you know when in which semester the student completed his latest Basic Course (sorted by Semester). The other column `TotalBasicSubjectsDoneTillNow` explains how many times had the student completed Basic Course(Subject) till now (sorted by Semester) ?

I think this is easy to solve with Joins as well as with UDFs but I want to use the power of existing analytical functions in BigQuery and solve it without joins.

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no "previous" or "till now" unless a column specifies that ordering.  Is that column `semester`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for your comment. The column semester is already ordered (in ascending order)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions for this -- assuming you have a column that specifies ordering.  Let me assume that column is `semester`:

```
select t.*,
       max( case when subject = 'Basic' then semester end ) over (partition by student order by semester end) as lastbasic,
       sum( case when subject = 'Basic' then 1 else 0 end ) over (partition by student order by semester end) as numbasictillnow    
from t
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *,
  LAST_VALUE(IF(subject='Basic',semester,NULL) IGNORE NULLS) OVER(win) AS WhenWasLastBasicSubjectDone ,
  COUNTIF(subject='Basic') OVER(win) AS TotalBasicSubjectsDoneTillNow     
FROM `project.dataset.table`
WINDOW win AS (PARTITION BY student ORDER BY semester)
```

You can test, play with above using dummy data from your question as below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 Student, 'Sub1' Subject, 'Sem1' Semester UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'Sub2', 'Sem2' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'Basic', 'Sem3' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'Basic', 'Sem4' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'Sub3', 'Sem5' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'Sub2', 'Sem6' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'Sub3', 'Sem7' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'Sub4', 'Sem8' 
)
SELECT *,
  LAST_VALUE(IF(subject='Basic',semester,NULL) IGNORE NULLS) OVER(win) AS WhenWasLastBasicSubjectDone ,
  COUNTIF(subject='Basic') OVER(win) AS TotalBasicSubjectsDoneTillNow     
FROM `project.dataset.table`
WINDOW win AS (PARTITION BY student ORDER BY semester)
-- ORDER BY Semester
```

Comment: Thanks @Mikhail .. As I can think by using OVER -- for each record we will be checking all the previous values in that partition making its complexity to be O(n*n) .. But with the help of UDF, I can solve it in O(n) . But the problem with UDF is that registering UDF in BigQuery is taking 7-8 seconds which is very large. Do you have any thoughts on this ?

Comment: Using Analytic/Windowed functions is the recommended way for such cases. While me personally, I am using UDF as a last resort, like for example when logic requires recursiveness. See one of my yesterday's answers for an example of such case

Comment: Can you please confirm if this is solving in O(n*n) or O(n) ? Since my dataset size is in billions I want to understand the complexity better so that my query performance is better.

Comment: I suggest to try whatever options you have and pick the best one :o) as of confirming - I am leaving this for googles to confirm